# Inserting data into different tables at the same time with Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Linq-to-SQL code here which submits data into the database in their respective table,
`PatientInformation` and `ResponsibleParty`:

```
public void addPatientInformation() { 
   using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){
      PatientInfo patientInfo = new PatientInfo();

      patientInfo.Phy_ID = physcianID;
      patientInfo.Pat_First_Name = txtFirstName.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Middle_Name = txtMiddleName.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Last_Name = txtLastName.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Gender = cmbGender.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Marital_Status = cmbMaritalStatus.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Date_Of_Birth = dtpDOB.Value;
      patientInfo.Pat_Home_Add = txtHomeAdd.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Home_Num = txtPhone.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Work_Add = txtWorkAdd.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Work_Num = txtWorkPhone.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Prim_Physician = txtPrimPhysician.Text;
      patientInfo.Pat_Ref_Physician = txtRefePhysician.Text;

      myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(patientInfo);
      myDb.SubmitChanges();
   }
}

public void addResponsiblePartyInformation() { 
   using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){
      ResponsibleParty responsibleParty = new ResponsibleParty();

      responsibleParty.Res_First_Name = txtResFirstName.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Middle_Init = txtResMiddleName.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Last_Name = txtResLName.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Gender = cmbResGender.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Marital_Status = cmbResMaritalStatus.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Date_Of_Birth = dtpResDOB.Value;
      responsibleParty.Res_Home_Add = txtResHomeAdd.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Home_Num = txtResPhone.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Work_Add = txtResWorkAdd.Text;
      responsibleParty.Res_Work_Num = txtResWorkPhone.Text;

      myDb.ResponsibleParties.InsertOnSubmit(responsibleParty);
      myDb.SubmitChanges();
   }
```

And a method named

```
public void submitInformationToDatabase() {
            addPatientInformation();
            addResponsiblePartyInformation();
            MessageBox.Show("Patient Demographics Has Been added.");
        }
```

Is there a way I could submit them at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can refactor your code to something resembling the example below, then both records will be inserted in the same `submit`.

```
using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){

      myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(patientInfo);
      myDb.ResponsibleParties.InsertOnSubmit(responsibleParty);
      myDb.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Two options:

- pass the data-context in and don't call `SubmitChanges()` every time (maybe make it optional)
- use a transaction

For the second, `TransactionScope` could be used to do this without having to change the two methods:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    method1(...);
    method2(...);
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Or with the other approach (after adding an optional parameter):

```
using(var ctx = new SomeDataContext(...)) {
    method1(ctx, ..., submitChanges: false);
    method2(ctx, ..., submitChanges: false);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting but so far I have no Idea what is a transanction scope is.

Comment: @user962206 it is an "ambient transaction", which can be used by multiple providers. In the case of SQL Server, it supports both the LTM and DTC ("lightweight transaction manager" and "distributed transaction coordinator") mechanisms. Or in English: you'll get a database transaction around that lot, so it is committed with the usual "ACID" rules.

Comment: can you provide examples? ?? I don't get method(cyx, ...,submitChanges: false); is there anything simpler?

Comment: @user the "simpler" is, as shown, transaction-scope. All I mean in them other setup is: rather than create the data-context inside those methods, create the data-context outside and pass it in as a parameter, then call SubmitChanges outside afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Pass connection as parameter with both method and use System.Transaction:

```
public void submitInformationToDatabase() {
         using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope tr = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
           {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbPath);
            con.Open();
            addPatientInformation(con);
            addResponsiblePartyInformation(con);
            tr.Complete();
           }
            MessageBox.Show("Patient Demographics Has Been added.");
        }
```

Comment: You seem to suggest using a connection-level transaction, but you illustrate an ambient transaction (TransactionScope). If using an ambient transaction, there is no change whatsoever required to the existing methods; you do not need to pass the connection in in this scenario. That said, it *will* help make it more likely to use the LTM rather than DTC - is this the intent you are trying to show?

Comment: Since both data context use same connection string so no need to open 2 connections and load more pooling, plus one "global" transaction by one connection

Comment: that won't happen; the data-contexts here are tightly scoped and will cleanly dispose (releasing back to the pool). Actually, it gets even more interesting because data-contexts can also (depending on how it is setup) release the connection whenever it isn't actively needed - iirc this is the default when passing in a connection string. This doesn't mean it had a different underlying connection each time.

Comment: Thanks for info, but anyway some times we need to set `Pooling=false` because it full after an hour of hard testing

Comment: if you have to turn pooling off, you're *possibly* getting something wrong (maybe not releasing them reliably?). If you genuinely need a bigger pool you can increase it. We use the standard pooling here at stackoverflow.